# TFS 2015: How to use CMMI (Portfolio-)Backlog work item types

Tags: tfs, project-management, tfs-workitem, azure-devops

We are using TFS 2015 together with the CMMI process template for work item tracking of our customer projects (where we not only deliver software).

I must say that I am not absolutely sure how to correctly use the different (Portfolio-)Backlog work item types and so far I have two main questions.

1. Is there a general rule when to use Requirements, Features or
   Epics?

I have seen [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee332488.aspx) that there is a parent/child releationship between them but it is not really clear to me when I need to add one more level of abstraction above Requirements (->Features) or Features (->Epics).

Initially I thought about using Requirements below Requirements in the backlog. One may have customer requirements on top leading to product requirements which may finally lead to software requirements. The basic idea in the VSO backlog seems to be to have only Tasks below Requirements and no further Requirements (at least the VSO web interface seems not to support adding Requirements below Requirements by default).

2. So what is the best practice to organize the backlog in such cases?
   Should we only use the Requirement work item type and create a
   parent/child relationship between those Requirements or are the work
   item types Feature and Epic made for that purpose?

Any explanation would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't any general rule about these portfolios for CMMI. But you may use the information about Agile Process as reference. See this link: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/182158/relationship-between-user-story-feature-and-epic

And just as you see in the instruction about CMMI process template. They are all parent/child relationship. So in your case, you could consider the customer requirement as "Epic" that can break down into several "Features" (Product requirements) and the "Features" can break down into several "Requirements" (Software requirements)

If you want to add a requirement as parent/child requirement, for example, add requirement B to requirement A as the child requirement, You can:

1. Open requirement A from the web interface.
2. Click "Links" button.
3. Click "Link to..." button.
4. Select "Child" link type and enter the ID of requirement B.
5. Click "OK" button and save the changes.

Comment: Thank you Eddie. Would you recommend to use a structure with 1.) Epics, Features and Requirements or 2.) Requirements with additional Sub-Requirements? Do you know about drawbacks of solution 2.) that one should be aware of (regarding using the full potential of VSO)?

Comment: I would recommend you to use Solution 1 since it is more convenient to adjust the parent/child relation ship and you can also track the status of items in each Portfolio via "Board". With Solution 2, all the items are placed in Required Portfolio while in the "Board" panel, it only show the items at the bottom level. That means you can only see "Software Requirements" from "Board" with Solution 2.

Answer (score 1):

Like Eddie mentioned, there is no strict guidelines when to use what type. The [Scaled Agile Framework](http://www.scaledagileframework.com/) has a great guidance which you can use.

For my feature team at Microsoft we use the Epics to have all strategic work captured (6-9 months). The feature teams track their work on the Feature backlog. This are the releasable units. And only those items which we are actually planning to work on in the next 3 months appear on the Requirements backlog. But that is just what works for my team.

Comment: Thanks Ewald for your remark and for pointing me to SAFe. However, for me it looks as if SAFe mainly focusses on pure SW development. In our case, software is just one part of the final (hardware) product that we sell to our customers. I am not sure how well it would fit in our case.

Comment: You are still releasing feature as part of the hardware product I guess. It doesn't really matter how you use it, as long as it works for you.